# Linux, timezone and dst

Tags: c, linux, timezone, dst

I'm using RHEL 5.3 (linux 2.6.18)

I have a legacy code that relies on timezone and dst returned by *ftime*(3).

Now from *ftime*(3) man pages I see that *timezone* and *dstflag* are not supported. 
Also in *gettimeofday*(3) those fields are not supported.

How I can retrieve timezone and dst?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tzset(3)`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    tzset();
    printf("%ld, %d\n", timezone, daylight);
}
```

Which on my system prints "-3600, 1".

`tzset` also fills the array `char *tzname[2]` with the names of the standard and daylight saving time timezone names.